# HTML5 canvas draw blocking animations from running correctly

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

So I have a big huge dataset that I'm plotting on an HTML5 canvas, so plotting it takes about 3 seconds. So in those three seconds, I need to show a loading bar to communicate to the user that things are happening. Basically, in this time, I'm drawing to an offscreen canvas that is used as a cache for the duration of the use of my app. I'd like to update a loading bar while this is happening, but for some reason jquery is ignoring my calls to resize the loading bar until AFTER the drawing has completed, and at that point the loading bar is sort of useless, as it just jumps to 100%

So here's the gist of what I'm trying to do...

```
function drawStuff() {
    for(p in points) {
        points[p].draw();
        updateLoadingBar(p/points.length);
    }

}


function updateLoadingBar(percent) {
    $('#loading_bar').width(percent+'%');
}
```

This code is a little simplistic. No, it's not actually getting the DOM element in the loop, but this is more concise and has the same result. The important thing is that the whole browser locks up and nothing happens. In any other language you'd just start up a worker thread to do this, but that's not an option here, so I'm wondering what the best approach to keeping a responsive UI while doing a lot of work is.

Thanks.